# Не работает смена переменной PHP+AJAX?

Tags: php, html, jquery, ajax

Ребята! Голова уже пухнет, мучаю этот вопрос:

Есть файл api_for_mobile.php который в приложение передает переменную $SALE = false; (означает что цены для акции скрыты) , когда мы редактируем ее на true, то цены в приложении меняются, к чему все это, мне не тяжело зайти и поменять с false на true, но хочется сделать так, чтобы человек заходил на отдельную страницу и нажав кнопку менял с false на true, могу прикрепить код для понимания

- change.html

  $('.change_false_or_true').click(function(){
     function change_php() {
              $.ajax(
                  {
                      type: "GET",
                      url:"api_for_mobile.php",
                      success: function (data) {
                          console.log(data)
                      },
                      error: function (xhr, str) {
                          console.log("error change_php");
                      }
                  })
      }
     change_php();
     })

  CHANGE
- api_for_mobile.php

  $getVar = clearVar($getVar);

  //if (statement) { // объявляем переменную $endDate как глобальную
    //  global $endDate;
      //$endDate = "16.10.2018";
      //}

  if(S_SESSION['sale']==false){$_SESSION['sale']=true;}
    else
      {$_SESSION['sale']=false;};

  ```
  if(!$_SESSION['sale']){$_SESSION['sale']=false}; //данную глобальную переменную необходимо прописать в php файле отвечаюшие за вывод цены для акции
  ```

  //$SALE = false; //заменить на $SALE = $_SESSION['sale'];

  ```
  if ($getVar == "pricing") { // цены
  $SALE = $_SESSION['sale'];
  $endDate = "21.10.2018";
  $array_pricing = array(
  "com.b2c.all.programs.1.month"              => array( "price" => "$2", 
  "discount" => "$1.49" ),
  "com.b2c.all.programs.3.month"              => array( "price" => "$5", 
  "discount" => "$3.49" ),
  "com.b2c.all.programs.6.month"              => array( "price" => "$9", 
  "discount" => "$6.49" ),
  "com.b2c.all.programs.12.month"             => array( "price" => "$12", 
  "discount" => "$8.49" ),
  "com.b2c.all.streams.1.month"               => array( "price" => "$2", 
  "discount" => "$1.49" ),
  "com.b2c.all.streams.3.month"               => array( "price" => "$5", 
  "discount" => "$3.49" ),
  "com.b2c.all.streams.6.month"               => array( "price" => "$9", 
  "discount" => "$6.49" ),
  "com.b2c.all.streams.12.month"              => array( "price" => "$12", 
  "discount" => "$8.49" ),
  "com.b2c.all.programs.all.streams.1.month"  => array( "price" => "$3", 
  "discount" => "$1.99" ),
  "com.b2c.all.programs.all.streams.3.month"  => array( "price" => "$7", 
  "discount" => "$4.99" ),
  "com.b2c.all.programs.all.streams.6.month"  => array( "price" => "$12", 
  "discount" => "$8.49" ),
  "com.b2c.all.programs.all.streams.12.month" => array( "price" => "$20", 
  "discount" => "$13.99" )
   );
  if ( !$_SESSION ) { //если акции нет, очищаем discount
  foreach ($array_pricing as &$price) {
  unset($price["discount"]);
  }
  } else {
  $array_pricing["endDate"] = $endDate;
  }
  echo json_encode( $array_pricing ); // вывод на страницу статуса
  }
  ```

Помогите!! А то я с ума сойду )

Comment: Ошибку то какую выдает??

Comment: @Anton Kucenko А вот дело в том что никакую ))

Answer (score 0):

Уважаемый @Тарас Лейтар все просто
замените

`if ( !$_SESSION ) { //если акции нет, очищаем discount`

на

```
if ( !$_SESSION['sale'] ) { //если акции нет, очищаем discount
```

также заменил бы

```
if(empty(S_SESSION['sale'])){$_SESSION['sale']=false;};
```

и последний штрих

```
$('.change_false_or_true').click(function(){ 
  sessionStorage['sale'] = true;
  window.location.reload()
})
```

Comment: Теперь так, и не работает, может что-то я упусти?

Comment: <html>
            <head>
            <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        
            <script>
           $('.change_false_or_true').click(function(){ 
           sessionStorage['sale'] = true;
           window.location.reload()
           })
           </script>
           </head>
           </html>
           <body>
            <button class="change_false_or_true">CHANGE</button>
            </body>

Comment: if(empty($_SESSION['sale'])){$_SESSION['sale']=false;};
   else
  {$_SESSION['sale']=false;};

Comment: if(!$_SESSION['sale']){$_SESSION['sale']=false};

Comment: проверьте значение сесси в браузере и на сервере визуально - на php print_r($_SESSION) и в меню браузера посмотреть сессии

Comment: Дело в том, что кнопка молчит, 0 действий

Comment: Я так понимаю что лучше подключится к БД и не морочить себе голову

Comment: Если кнопка молчит, то явяскрипт подгружается раньше отрисовки кнопки, в этом случае используйте $(document).on('click','.change_false_or_true',Function(){});

Comment: и вбейте в браузере в консоль $('.change_false_or_true') - должен отобразиться объект, если пишет undefined - значит вы не правильно обращаетесь к дом элементу

Comment: Короче, пойду я подключаться к БД, а то это жесть, одно отпало, второе работает, еще на /api шлется json {"query":"pricing"}. Взамен приходят параметры скидок. Это как работает приложение на телефоне с файлом api_for_mobile.php